# Properties of congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is there an established result or properties concerning the congruence below?

$$ax+b\equiv 0\pmod{ay+b}.$$

Clearly, if $x=y$, our congruence holds.

Aside from this, when will be the congruence hold?

Comment: For arbitrary $a,b$ ,it is not possible unless $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $m=ay+b$.
Then
\begin{align}
ax+b
&=ax+m-ay\\
&\equiv a(x-y)\pmod m
\end{align}
If $d=\gcd(a,b)$, then
$$ax+b\equiv 0\pmod m\iff x\equiv y\pmod{\frac md}$$

Comment: The last part is confusing.

Comment: why gcd of a and b?

Comment: d=gcd(a,b)=gcd(a, ay+b)=gcd(a,m)